# What Bootstrap or css style can do this?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have css style like in image.  I could not find it in Bootstrap and can not remember what it is called in css style.  Can anyone tell me how to style it?

Thanks.
[image: Form label]

Comment: you mean `<legend>` ?

Comment: Yes.  I found that using fieldset and legend will get what I need in css style.  I wonder if there is something like that in Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: you can use legend tag in twitter bootstrp too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even do it with some Math+CSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.outer {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: max-content;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background: white;
}

.left {
  left: 10px;
}

.right {
  right: 10px;
}

.center {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="block left">Left Title</div>

</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="block center">Center Title</div>

</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="block right">Right Title</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The legend element</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
 <fieldset style="height:200px;">
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>

 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This design can be achieved using  tag in HTML.

To know more about the Legend tag, see the link below.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp

Example of Legend Tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_legend